# Weird Google sign-on behaviour on stackexchange

Tags: bug, login, sign-up

I was logged in to stackoverflow and just registered to https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/, chose the usual single-sign-on via Google (was already logged in and just had to press the "Accept" button), and then webmasters.stackexchange.com showed a message like "Something has gone wrong - not your fault, don't worry!". Nevertheless I noticed that I had been logged in, but with the weird username [a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/73478/a25bedc5-3d09-41b8-82fb-ea6c353d75ae), and I didn't get the usual 100 trusted start rep. Now it seems my usual username (this one) and that new one are somehow connected, but for example webmasters doesn't show up in the "Your Communities" dropdown menu of this account.

What's going on here? Looks like Google single-sign-on is broken for some reason?

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've seen earlier reports of this but can't find it. I don't recall  that it is something you can resolve your self. A dev need to poke into the database to rectify whatever went wrong there. Not your fault I think.

Comment: Yeah, not sure what went south there. This is an internally "default" username we use that's supposed to be replaced by the time a user is created. We fixed one instance of that not happening a while back, so this is either a regression or a new issue. I'll take a look next week, but in the meantime, I'm fixing up your profile. Thanks for the report! (Mental note for future me: all the fields showed up fine on profile edit screen, so likely something's broken just on display and/or in AccountSiteProfiles.)

Comment: @AdamLear Cool, thanks very much! If it helps, I've had the same issue today with https://pypi.python.org/pypi - press "Login with Google" there, and nothing happens except a page refresh (the first time I got the login & "Accept" button, but it never logged me in). So either it's a coincidence and their page has a Google sign-on issue as well, or something is suddenly weird with my Google account. But from my experience it will be hard if not impossible to contact Google about it, so I'm not sure what I can do.

Comment: @Ela782 FWIW, this is very likely something on our end, nothing to do with Google per se.

Comment: @AdamLear Yea, indeed it seems like the pypi issue was a coincidence - I found out they have another issue :-)

Comment: @AdamLear second report on MSE for what looks like the same issue: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/289134/did-not-receive-site-association-bonus-100-rep#289134

Comment: Almost the exact same happened to me as seen in the link indicated above by rene

Comment: @AdamLear And another one [Error joining community: not "trusted in other communities" rep](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/289140)